# How I can merge two different data sets?

Tags: r, dataset

I have two data set as below
df1 :

```
ID   name 
1   
1   
2   
2   
3   
3   
3
```

df2 :

```
ID   var1 name 
1     54   aaa
1     12   aaa
2     55   bbb
2     87   bbb
3     1    ccc
3     2    ccc
3     12   ccc
3     14   ccc   
3     16   ccc   
...
```

I want to fill the nave variable in the df1 data by using df2.
How should I do that?

Comment: It has been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: if there are "ID"s that exist only df2 data and I want to merge data sets by only using commonly existed "ID"?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick trial.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,2), name=c('aaa','bbb','bbb'))
# get unique ID and name pairs
df2 <- unique(df2)

# merge that keep all x rows (or left outer join by df1)
merge(df1, df2, by="ID", all=TRUE)
  ID name
1  1  aaa
2  2  bbb
3  3 <NA>

## Update
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3))

names <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), names=c('aaa','bbb','ccc'))
df2 <- merge(data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)), names, by="ID") 
df2 <- unique(df2)

merge(df1, df2, by="ID", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that but it does not work properly, so I asked.

Comment: I don't know why number of df1's row gets larger.

Comment: Could you try merge(df1, df2, by="ID", all.x = TRUE) instead? The above would be cross join while this one should be left-join that keeps all df1 records. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Yes I did. I don't know why # of rows of df1 gets larger.

Comment: if there are "ID"s that exist only df2 data and I want to merge data sets by only using commonly existed "ID"?

Comment: Check if df2 has unique pairs or I'm not sure what you mean. The updated code won't increase # records of df1.

Comment: You are right. That was the problem. Do you know how I can drop out observations which do not exist in both data sets?

Comment: try 'all = FALSE' instead of 'all.x = TRUE'

Comment: sorry that it does not work in my data sets. I think I need to remain "ID"s which exist in both data, firstly.